# Matrices and Linear Transformations proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$T:V \rightarrow V$

$A$ is a matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $E$. Show that if $A$ is diagonalizable then every matrix representation of $T$ is diagonalizable.
[You may assume that any other matrix representation of T is of the form
$X^{-1}AX$ where $X$ is an invertible matrix.]

What does this even mean? $A$ represents $T$. The definition of $A$ being diagonalisable is precisely if $T$ is diagonisable. Where do I even begin?

I dont understand more generally questions like this which ask to show that facts about $A$ being true iff they are true for $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if there exists a basis $E_d$ such that the matrix $D$ of  $T$ is diagonal which means that there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that

$$D=P^{-1}AP$$
Now take any matrix representation of $T$ say $B=X^{-1}AX$ then we have

$$B=(PX)^{-1}D(PX)$$
hence $B$ is diagonalizable since it's similar to $D$.